# Android search query returning null list

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

For my app I am using an sqllite database to make a movie logging app. A movie object has the title, a boolean for whether the user has already seen the movie or not and whether they have it on their watchlist

I am able to add a movie to the sqllite database, but when I run a search query to return a list of Movie object, I try get a null pointer exception when I try to display the results in a Listview.

This is my movie object's variable types

```
public class Movie implements Serializable {
private String movieTitle;
private boolean seen; //true if user has seen movie
private boolean addToWatchlist; //if user wants to add movie to watchlist
```

This is my table and ts fields

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_MOVIE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + MOVIE_TABLE + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_SEEN + " INT," + KEY_WATCHLIST + " INT " + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_MOVIE_TABLE);
}
```

My addMovie method

```
public void addMovie(Movie m) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TITLE, m.getmMovieTitle());

    if (m.isSeen()) {
        values.put(KEY_SEEN, 1);
    }
    else {values.put(KEY_SEEN,0);}

    if (m.isAddWatchlist()) {
        values.put(KEY_WATCHLIST, 1);
    }
    else {values.put(KEY_WATCHLIST,0);}
    System.out.println(values.toString());

    db.insert(MOVIE_TABLE, null, values);
    db.close();
```

And the Select Query which is the source  of all my problems. Resulting in a null list even after adding movies that have been seen, where I set seen = 1;

```
public ArrayList<Movie> getSeenMovies(){
    ArrayList<Movie> seenList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + MOVIE_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_SEEN + " == " +1;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Movie m = new Movie();
            m.setMovieTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            m.setSeen(true);

            m.setAddWatchlist(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)) == 1);

            seenList.add(m);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return seenList;
}
```

The NullPointerException comes when I try to populate my listview with the query results because of the movieList.size() in the getCount method of my MovieArrayAdapter class which says my movieList is null

MovieArrayAdapter

```
public class MovieArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Movie> movieList;

//adapter constructor
public MovieArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Movie> movieList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.movieList = movieList;
}

//abstract method returns size of movie list
public int getCount() {
        return this.movieList.size();
}

//abstract method returns item at input position in list
public Object getItem(int pos){return this.movieList.get(pos);}

// abstract method gets item id at position i
public long getItemId(int pos){return pos;}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    View v = View.inflate(context, R.layout.movie_list_entry, null);

    //finds MovieTitle textview field in the movie_list entry layout file
    TextView title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.MovieTitle);

    //sets MovieTitle field to title of movie from list
    title.setText(movieList.get(position).getmMovieTitle());

    return v;}
}
```

The error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.indiana.kupshah.movdex, PID: 4754
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.indiana.kupshah.movdex/com.indiana.kupshah.movdex.SeenList}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
                  at com.indiana.kupshah.movdex.MovieArrayAdapter.getCount(MovieArrayAdapter.java:32)
                  at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:493)
                  at com.indiana.kupshah.movdex.SeenList.onCreate(SeenList.java:27)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

DBHandler movdexDB = new DBHandler(this); is an instance variable for the add movie form

This adds movie to the db when add button is clicked

```
public void onAddButtonClick(View v){
    EditText movieTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TitleText);
    CheckBox seen = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.SeenCheck);
    CheckBox watch = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.WatchCheck);

    //converts View values to types suitable for Movie class
    String addTitle = movieTitle.getText().toString();
    Boolean addSeen = seen.isChecked();
    Boolean addWatch = watch.isChecked();

    Movie movie = new Movie (addTitle,addSeen,addWatch);

    movdexDB.addMovie(movie);
}
```

This is the button click that starts the SeenList Activity

```
public void onSeenButtonClick(View v){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(AddMovieEntry.this,SeenList.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("seen_list", movdexDB.getSeenMovies());
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

And lastly, the SeenList onCreate method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_seen_list);

    //finds list view and populates from movies from the seen list,
    //using the layout established in the MovieAdapter arrayadapter class
    ListView SeenListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.SeenList);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    ArrayList<Movie> seenList;
    //sets the list of seen and watched movies
    seenList = (ArrayList<Movie>) i.getSerializableExtra("seenlist_movies");
    MovieArrayAdapter myAdapter = new MovieArrayAdapter(this, seenList);
    SeenListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}
```

Comment: please post the stacktrace of the exception

Comment: Okay just added it

Comment: You'll need to follow the stacktrace in your classes that aren't included here: `com.indiana.kupshah.movdex.MovieArrayAdapter.getCount(MovieArrayAdapter.java:32)` and `com.indiana.kupshah.movdex.MovieArrayAdapter.getCount(MovieArrayAdapter.java:32)`

Comment: Added the MovieArrayAdapter to the post, since the the MovieArrayAdapter class extends BaseAdapter, it requires the field getCount() which returns the size of the list of objects. What I understand is that the app crashes because the getCount method uses ArraryList.size(), and the array list being provided by the SQL query is null. @Gary

Comment: `getSeenMovies` never returns null, so there must be a problem between the moment when you get the movie list from the db and the moment when you put it in the adapter. Post that part of the code too. (that method : `SeenList.onCreate`)

Comment: @njzk2 just added additional methods, used for this

Comment: @njzk2 In the passing activity's class, when i call getSeenMovies(), the correct arraylist of movies is returned, so yes it has to be in the activitiy switch that my receiving activity is translating it to a null object

Comment: `"seen_list"` != `"seenlist_movies"`. You need to use the same key.

Comment: yeah i just saw that a few hours ago - felt pretty embarrassed afterwards, fixed it! thanks! @njzk2

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you just need to protect access for null values in MovieArrayAdapter:

```
public int getCount(){            
  return movieList != null ? movieList.size() : 0;
}
```

Comment: So that prevents the application from crashing, but the main problem that i am having is that the select query is returning a null ArraryList even after i add movies to it such that there should be a result from the query

Comment: oh I see.  Check out your select query statement.  Is that really what you want? ' == ' looks suspicious to me.

Comment: I've been running it on sqlfiddler and it is giving me the results i want, not sure why its not working here

Comment: that solves the npe temporarily, but that does not solve the fact that the list is null when the object itself is null when `getSeenMovies` clearly never returns null

Comment: If you would like help with your problem, please do not downvote solutions that fix the error you posted, even though it apparently isn't complete.

Comment: @Gary i didn't downvote you :/, i appreciate your help